# Sqlalchemy 2. Get related object with 'where'

Tags: sqlalchemy

Here are sqlalchemy 2.0 models:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    
class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "product"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

class ProductsRemains(Base):
    __tablename__ = "products_remains"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('product.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
```

I need to get Product object + ProductsRemains. I am able to do it with the code below, but I need ProductReemains only with a specific user_id. How can I do that?

```
async def get_product_with_remains(self, user_id: int, items_id: Iterable) -> list[Product]:
    stmt = (
        select(Product)
        .where(Product.id.in_(items_id))
        .options(
            selectinload(Product.remains)
            # I need to load remains only with current user_id
        )
    )
    result = await self.session.execute(stmt)
    return result.scalars().all()
```